# If Earth spun faster, would I be able to jump higher?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, planets, centrifugal-force

I'm asking mostly in relation to the forces acting on a person, but it would also be nice to know if there would be any impact on muscle strength, similar to when an astronaut goes into space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would gravity change on a planet rotating around itself very fast?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63565/)