# Do we feel the full force of the earths gravity even though the earth is spinning?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, earth, centrifugal-force

As far as I know, since the earth is spinning, centrifugal force should be throwing you off the earth. However, gravity counteracts that by being a stronger force. So if you stood an object with the exact mass and size of earth, but it wasn't spinning, would you perceive gravity to be stronger?

If this is true, wouldn't an object outside of the atmosphere not in orbit of the earth have greater acceleration than an object in orbit?

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9751/

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63565/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44931/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10670/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12487/